# Yup validations OR condition with condional validations

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, yup

I have these 3 fields.

```
dateType: null | String,
fromDate: null | Date,
toDate: null | Date,
```

if the `dateType` is not null, `fromDate` or `toDate` is required.

if both `fromDate` and `toDate` are selected, `fromDate` must be less than the `toDate`

How do I achieve this with Yup validations?

Comment: Perhaps you should add what you have tried and outline your one challenge with that and the actual expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got your answer, by chance if not you can try this -

```js
yup.object().shape({
  dateType: yup.string().nullable(),
  fromDate: yup.date().transform((v) => (moment(v).isValid() ? moment(v) : null)).nullable().when('dateType',{
    is: (d)=>d,
    then:yup.date().required().typeError('this date is required').max(yup.ref('toDate'), 'Fromm-Date  must be less than the To-date')
  }),
  toDate: yup.date().transform((v) => (moment(v).isValid() ? moment(v) : null)).nullable().when('dateType',{
    is: (d)=>d,
    then:yup.date().required().typeError('this date is required')
  })
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).